# creating a php array and then convert to a javascript array using MySQL data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, database

i am trying to create an array using data from a MySQL database, this is to create a data tree using treant js (best method i could find) and i came to the conclusion that i have to create the array first in php and then json_encode() it in order for it to function properly. My question is how do I make the php array with the following format and how do I convert it using json_enconde ?

the code from the javascript that constructs the data tree is the following:

```
 Array approach
var config = {
    container: "#collapsable-example",

    animateOnInit: true,

    node: {
        collapsable: true
    },
    animation: {
        nodeAnimation: "easeOutBounce",
        nodeSpeed: 700,
        connectorsAnimation: "bounce",
        connectorsSpeed: 700
    }
},
malory = {
    image: "img/malory.png"
},

lana = {
    parent: malory,
    image: "img/lana.png"
}

figgs = {
    parent: lana,
    image: "img/figgs.png"
}

sterling = {
    parent: malory,
    childrenDropLevel: 1,
    image: "img/sterling.png"
},

woodhouse = {
    parent: sterling,
    image: "img/woodhouse.png"
},

pseudo = {
    parent: malory,
    pseudo: true
},

cheryl = {
    parent: pseudo,
    image: "img/cheryl.png"
},

pam = {
    parent: pseudo,
    image: "img/pam.png"
},

chart_config = [config, malory, lana, figgs, sterling, woodhouse, pseudo, pam, cheryl];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: First of all you will need to spell the function correctly `json_encode()`

Comment: Second that's an object not an array (`chart_config` is an array). Here's a tip: `$config = new stdClass();` when posting a question you need to actually post code you have tried and the errors you are getting.

Comment: It really makes no sense to define a whole heap of variables and then assemble them into an array like that when you could declare an array of objects straight up in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't tell us anything about your mysql data, all I can tell you is that the php equivalent to the array you show above would be (in part):

```
$woodhouse = [
    'parent' => $sterling,
    'image' => 'img/woodhouse.png',
},
```

`json_encode` will then create JSON that looks like this for woodhouse:

```
{
    parent: {
        parent: { /* malory data here */ },
        childrenDropLevel: 1,
        image: "img/sterling.png"
    },
    image: "img/woodhouse.png"
},
```

The important thing to recognize is that the `stirling` object in the original was also encoded recursively. JSON does not support object references like you have in your example.

I suspect (but can't really know) that the JSON you actually need to create will look more like the data that came from your database — including an id for each person and the "parent" field holding the id of the parent, rather than a reference.

Once that data comes over the wire, you can create the structure with references in your javascript client.

Comment: Also, Archer: 1999 coming soon!